# Is there any Twitter app for Mac to update my status, no timeline?

Tags: macos, twitter

I'm looking for a Twitter client for Mac that could just update my status, no need for timeline, mentions or groups support. Just an icon on the menubar and/or key combination that will give me a textbox to fill and send. TwitPic and bit.ly support would be ideal.

[MoodBlast](http://blog.circlesixdesign.com/download/moodswing/) looked like an almost perfect match, but it lacks OAuth support, so it's useless now.

Answer (score 1):

[Wren](http://wrenapp.com/) seems like it will do what you need.

> Wren saves you time by letting you tweet without seeing your timeline. It also comes with several features like username autocompletion, link shortening and drafts to make it easy to tweet during your busy work day.

Comment: Yes! +1 for first valid answer, thanks. Shame it's $4 though.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Dashboard widget called Twidget. It does update the timeline (you can set the refresh time to 60 minutes) but it would be easy to ignore...

You can find it [here](http://gettwidget.com/).

Comment: Same as MoodBlast, it doesn't support OAuth, so it's useless now (unless the developers update it)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has an app. It's available in the Mac App Store. You can hide the main window and use the icon in the menu bar to add a status.

Comment: when I tweet, it brings up the main window. Can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Not sure. Try the Settings.